# How can I check a public master address balance?

Tags: balance, bip32-hd-wallets

I have an extended public key, I need to check it's balance (I have no connection to wallet), is there a third party service for that ? 
Edit: This is not a bitcoin address. This generates multiple new addresses each time and I want a method to check the total balance given only the master public key .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably mean [extended key](https://bitcoin.org/en/glossary/extended-key). There are extended public keys (xpub) and extended private keys (xpriv).

An example xpub would be:

> xpub6CUGRUonZSQ4TWtTMmzXdrXDtypWKiKrhko4egpiMZbpiaQL2jkwSB1icqYh2cfDfVxdx4df189oLKnC5fSwqPfgyP3hooxujYzAu3fDVmz

They always start with *xpub* or *xpriv*.

You could use  [https://blockchain.info/xpub/](https://blockchain.info/xpub/%3Cyour-xpub-goes-here%3E) or [goochain.net](https://goochain.net/) or Electrum as a view-only wallet.

Comment: What about keys that start with "zpub". Where do you check balance online for these?

Comment: Yes try an explorer like blockonomics that support segwit xpubs https://blog.blockonomics.co/a-segwit-blockexplorer-47cd516dd8c5

Comment: @darkknight Do you know of an API that supports fetching a total balance for a zpub address? https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/116038/how-to-retrieve-total-btc-held-in-ledger-wallet/116040#116040 Thanks.

Comment: @ryan yes, I posted an answers on that question

Answer (score 0):

so do i understand this correctly that you have a paper wallet public address, or a public address of a wallet you currently cannot access. But you want to check the amount of bitcoin it holds? If so, you just have to go to blockchain.info and copy/paste the public address into the white search box at the top right-hand part of the screen, then hit 'ENTER'. This will show you the amount of bitcoin on the blockchain that was sent to/from that public address.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to install the wallet software that was used to create that wallet and restore the wallet using the master public key. This will create a watch-only wallet.

Alternatively if the key is a bip32 xpub and the derivation path is bip44 then you can view the addresses generated with it on blockchain.info. Just paste in the xpub in the search box on that site.

Note that electrum does not use bip44 so if it's an electrum wallet then you should just create a watch-only wallet.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an extended public key, I would recommend that you use [Blockpath](https://blockpath.com/wallets/new?action=appxpub) to scan it. It goes through the most popular derivation paths to check for any spent or unspent funds.

Answer (score 0):

[Links in Answer above](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/63051/26481) are outdated/not working. Here is the updated answer. As of Nov 2022, following third party services are showing extended public key balance:

- [Blockpath](https://blockpath.com/)
- [Blockonomics](https://blockonomics.co/)
- Directly visiting the URL https://www.blockchain.com/btc/xpub/*your_xpub_here*. Searching xpub via UI on blockchain.com btc explorer is failing